# unknown error in c. this program not going to void Linear_Search() function

Tags: c

```
/int arr[n]; int n;/
void Linear_Search() {
  int i, q, flag = 0, num, n;
  int arr[n];
  printf("Enter the number of array\n");
  scanf("%d", n);
  printf("Enter the numbers from which searched\n");
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++); {
    scanf("%d", & arr[i]);
  }
  printf("enter the number to be searched\n");
  scanf("%d", & q);
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (q == arr[i]); {
      num = q;
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
  if (flag == 1) printf("found! number is %d", num);
  else printf("number not present in group\n");
  getch();
}
void main() {
  printf("ALL SEARCHING TECHNIQUE\n");
  printf("Choices\n");
  printf("1.Linear Search\n2.Binary Search\n3.Interpolation Search\n4.Jump Search\n");
  void Linear_Search();
  int select, l = 1;
  scanf("%d", & select);
  switch (select) {
  case 1:
    printf("This is Linear Search\n");
    void Linear_Search();
    break;
  }
  /case 2: printf("This is Binary Search\n"); void Binary_Search(); break; case 3: printf("This is Interpolation Search\n"); void Interpolation_Search(); break; case 4: printf("This is Jump Search\n"); void Jump_Search(); break; } printf("To continue PRESS 1 or PRESS ANY KEY"); scanf("%d",&l);/
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Comment: You declare the function at `printf("1.Linear Search\n2.Binary Search\n3.Interpolation Search\n4.Jump Search\n");
  void Linear_Search();
  int select, l = 1;` — if you want to call it, omit the `void`.  You also declare `void Binary_Search();` but don't call it, which is why your compilation succeeds even though you've not defined the function.

Comment: case 2 to case 4 i added in comment. and i overlooked that void part. and as i am including void function call becomes function protoype so it getting compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the return type of the function at the places where you are trying to call them. This turns them from a function call to a function prototype declaration. Remove the return type (void in these cases) at the places where the function shall be called.